# Recursive function without return statement

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, recursion

I have some data that is inserted into a nested dictionary. The data are created and could theoretically be endlessly deep. It could e.g. looks like this:

```
data = {'leaves': {'dark': {}, 'green': {'light': {}}, 'without': {'veins': {'blue': {}}}, '5': {}}}
```

For some clarification: In this small sample, it means that a certain plant has 'leaves', the 'leaves' are 'dark', 'green' and 'without'. The 'green' is 'light' in this example etc.

I want to unnest this dictionary and store every key, value combination into a tuple. That could for example look like this:

```
[('leaves', 'dark'), ('leaves', 'green'), ('green', 'light'), ('without', 'veins'), ('leaves', '5'), ('veines', 'blue')]
```

**Note**: order is not important. For those interested, these tuples are further manipulated and will end up in a knowledge graph.

I thought a recursive function would do the trick here, but my function works best without the restatement, a function without a return statement is just a simple loop. However, I cannot make it work with a simple loop.

*edit*: the doubles variable is a global list.

The function I wrote:

```
def undict(d):
    for key in d.keys():
        if isinstance(d[key], dict):
            doubles += [(key, k) for k in d[key].keys()]
        undict(d[key]) # Normally: return undict(d[key])
```

Maybe can anyone offer some insights on how to make it truly recursive or use a simple loop? I am lost at this point.

Comment: You're building the list `doubles`, but not actually *doing* anything with it.

Comment: Yes apologies, I edited the question a bit. Doubles is a global list.

Comment: Are you missing `('leaves', 'without')` in your sample output, or am I misunderstnding something?

Comment: Are you sure you want `('leaves', 'green')` and `('green', 'light')` as two separate elements, rather than `('leaves', 'green', 'light')` as one element?

Comment: Yes separate elements are preferred, in the connections are maintained with a knowledge graph because of the subject and object are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is pretty good!

However, note that you're using a global variable, `doubles`, rather than a local variable and a `return` statement, which would be cleaner.

To avoid issues with `.append` or `.extend` or `+=` with lists, a very pythonic approach is to use a generator function, using keyword `yield` instead of keyword `return`.

```py
data = {'leaves': {'dark': {}, 'green': {'light': {}}, 'without': {'veins': {'blue': {}}}, '5': {}}}

def undict_to_pairs(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):  # always true with your example data
            for subk in v:
                yield (k, subk)
            yield from undict_to_pairs(v)
        else:
            yield (k,v)          # this statement is never reached with your example data

print(list(undict_to_pairs(data)))
# [('leaves', 'dark'), ('leaves', 'green'), ('leaves', 'without'), ('leaves', '5'), ('green', 'light'), ('without', 'veins'), ('veins', 'blue')]
```

Note that with your example data, `isinstance(v,dict)` is always true. The `else` branch is never reached. So this shorter version would work too:

```py
def undict_to_pairs(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        for subk in v:
            yield (k, subk)
        yield from undict_to_pairs(v)

print(list(undict_to_pairs(data)))
# [('leaves', 'dark'), ('leaves', 'green'), ('leaves', 'without'), ('leaves', '5'), ('green', 'light'), ('without', 'veins'), ('veins', 'blue')]
```

Let me also suggest a different version, which is not what you asked for but looks more logical to me in regards to your data: generating long tuples instead of pairs. I removed `isinstance(v, dict)` from that version, since it appears the values in your data are always dicts.

```py
def undict_to_tuples(d, acc = ()):
    if d == {}:
        yield acc
    else:
        for k,v in d.items():
            yield from undict_to_tuples(v, acc + (k,))

print(list(undict_to_tuples(data)))
# [('leaves', 'dark'), ('leaves', 'green', 'light'), ('leaves', 'without', 'veins', 'blue'), ('leaves', '5')]
```

Comment: This is a very complete answer! Thank you! I was not familiar with .extend, but looking into the documentation it seems very useful. Yielding from and iterable is indeed much cleaner in this case.

Comment: @Robert Ehrm. Sorry. My first comment about `+=` and `.extend` was wrong. I removed it.

Comment: Yes I saw. Thanks btw for the Else statement. While it is now always True, in future work this might come in handy!

Comment: I want to thank you for suggesting a different version. I am not quite done yet, but I think in the end I'll use the version where you accumulate the data, as you suggested. 

Thank you!